# find the 8 letter Word

Tags: wordplay

> What 8 letter word can have a letter taken away and it still makes a word.  Take another letter away and it still makes a word. Keep on doing that until you have one letter left. What is the word?

Answer (score 6):

My answer is

> LEATHERY, LEATHER, LATHER, LATHE, LATE, ATE, AT, A

there could be another answers.

Answer (score 6):

only 8? then skip the first one:

> ```
>  STARTLING
>
>  START.ING
>  STAR..ING
>  ST.R..ING
>  ST....ING
>  S.....ING
>  S.....IN.
>  ......IN.
>  ......I..
> ```